# How to correctly use malloc in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

I'm trying to allocate some memory using malloc in my program (I don't have much experience with malloc as I am just starting to learn how to use it). The program I've created works but I don't think I've used malloc correctly and I want to learn how to use it correctly.

The basic idea of my program is it takes 3 lines of input. The first line being whether you want to sort it by odd or even, the second line being how large your array is and the third line being the integers in the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char* sort;
int n;
int* ar;
int i;

void test()

{
    int temp;
    int j = 1;

    if (strcmp(sort, "odd") == 0) {

        for (i = 0; i < n;) {

            if (j != n) {

                if (ar[i] % 2 != 0) {

                    if (ar[j] % 2 != 0) {

                        if (ar[j] < ar[i]) {

                            temp = ar[i];
                            ar[i] = ar[j];
                            ar[j] = temp;
                            j++;
                        }
                        else {
                            j++;
                        }
                    }
                    else {

                        j++;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    j++;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            else {

                i++;
                j = i + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if (strcmp(sort, "even") == 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            if (j != n) {

                if (ar[i] % 2 == 0) {

                    if (ar[j] % 2 == 0) {

                        if (ar[j] < ar[i]) {

                            temp = ar[i];
                            ar[i] = ar[j];
                            ar[j] = temp;
                            j++;
                        }
                        else {
                            j++;
                        }
                    }
                    else {

                        j++;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    j++;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            else {

                i++;
                j = i + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

void main()
{

    ar = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    sort = malloc(sizeof(char) + 5);

    printf("Enter odd or even\n");
    scanf("%s", sort);

    printf("Enter the size of the array \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Enter the elements of the array \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        scanf("%d", &ar[i]);
    }

    test();

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        printf("%d ", ar[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you're using it properly. Just remember to free memory before the program terminates

Comment: in malloc you are allocating space for  10 integer but , asking the user to enter any size this will lead to runtime error as user can enter more than 10

Comment: `ar = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);` after  `scanf("%d", &n);`.

Comment: It depends on your definition of "correct". Your syntax is fine. But the logic is not ideal. `malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);` would be better written as `malloc(sizeof(int) * n);` so that it can store the right number of elements specified by the user. Also, no need to use `malloc` for a small fixed size buffer. So could have more simply just done: `char sort[MAX_LEN];`. Finally, avoid global variables.

Comment: You also want to *Avoid Using Global Variables* when not absolutely necessary (such as for use in a *callback function* where the declaration is fixed). You could declare all of your globals in `main` and pass them as parameters as needed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait until they tell you the size of the array, and then use `malloc()` to allocate an array that size.

You don't need to use `malloc` for `sort`, you can just declare that as an ordinary array. In general, you use `malloc()` either when you need to allocate a dynamic number of items, or when the size of the item is dynamic, you don't need it for a single item with a fixed size.

```
int *ar;
char sort[5];

void main()
{    
    printf("Enter odd or even\n");
    scanf("%s", sort);

    printf("Enter the size of the array \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    ar = malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    printf("Enter the elements of the array \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &ar[i]);
    }

    test();

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", ar[i]);
    }
}
```